# In JavaFX using JxBrowser invokeAndWaitFinishLoadingMainFrame() method crashes JVM

Tags: javafx, jxbrowser

I'm experimenting with the  JXBrowser Chromium browser engine in JavaFX on Mac OS Sierra. I would like to wait until the URL is fully loaded after I call browser.goBack() or browser.goForward() methods so I can check the Navigation History. The simple app below crashes the JVM but the same code works fine in Java (Swing). The same call in a Java swing app works without any issues.  Does anyone have any idea why?

```
public class JavaFXSample extends Application {
@Override
public void init() throws Exception {
    // On Mac OS X Chromium engine must be initialized in non-UI thread.
    if (Environment.isMac()) {
        BrowserCore.initialize();
    }
}

@Override
public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {
    Browser browser = new Browser();
    BrowserView view = new BrowserView(browser);

    Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(view), 700, 500);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(WindowEvent t) {
            Platform.exit();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    Browser.invokeAndWaitFinishLoadingMainFrame(browser, new Callback<Browser>
    () {
        @Override
        public void invoke(Browser browser) {
            browser.loadURL("http://www.google.com");
        }
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've faced a deadlock because you create the Browser instance in heavyweight mode. You can try solving this issue by using the "jxbrowser.ipc.external=true" VM parameter that enables lightweight rendering mode and runs Chromium engine in separate native process to avoid deadlocks in UI thread.